# How to convert varchar 1,760,862.8185919 to float in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to convert varchar 1,760,862.8185919 to float in SQL Server 2012 or decimal?

```
DECLARE @n varchar(100) = '1,760,862.8185919'
DECLARE @f float = ??
```

Comment: @Cory in this case sql server 2012 and  TRY_CONVERT function is better answer, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it, but remove the commas first:

```
DECLARE @n varchar(100) = '1,760,862.8185919'
```

To convert with `CAST`, do this:

```
DECLARE @f float = CAST(REPLACE(@n, ',', '') AS FLOAT)
```

Alternatively, use `CONVERT`:

```
DECLARE @f float = CONVERT(float, REPLACE(@n, ',', ''))
```

And you can convert back (with loss of precision) by first converting to `MONEY` then `VARCHAR`:

```
DECLARE @new_n VARCHAR(100) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@f AS MONEY), 1)
```

Comment: +1 . . . You seem to be first.

Comment: You are the First. How can I format float to string with the same coma format? 1760862.8185919 to 1,760,862.82. Has SQL server the function to format float to string with coma separator?

Comment: Well it's generally not a good idea to use SQL Server for these types of tasks and instead do the conversion in your application or business layer. Having said that, I'll update my answer.

Comment: An additional warning, not all countries use commas and periods in the same way. For example, lots of Europe has number in this format `1.760.862,8185919`

Comment: @DavidG It's OK, It's for US. I cannot change business layer (black box) :(

Comment: @garik No problem, I just mention it as a recommendation. I realise that the 'real world' often prevents these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @n varchar(100) 
set @n = '1,760,862.8185919'
select convert(float,Replace(@n,',',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

The commas are probably your issue, so just remove them before doing the conversion:

```
DECLARE @f float = CONVERT(float, REPLACE(@n, ',', ''))
```

Or

```
DECLARE @f decimal(20, 8) = CONVERT(decimal(20, 8), REPLACE(@n, ',', ''))
```

Taking advantage of SQL Server 2012 features, you may want to use `TRY_CONVERT` instead:

```
DECLARE @f float = TRY_CONVERT(float, REPLACE(@n, ',', ''))
```

Or

```
DECLARE @f decimal(20, 8) = TRY_CONVERT(decimal(20, 8), REPLACE(@n, ',', ''))
```

The result will be `NULL` if the conversion fails (instead of raising an error).

Comment: +1 be safer! Can I convert float to string back (after some rounding) to the same comma format string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select @f = cast(replace(@n, ',', '') as float);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DECLARE @n varchar(100) = '1,760,862.8185919'
DECLARE @f NUMERIC(25,10) 

SET @f = CAST(REPLACE(@n,',','') AS NUMERIC(25,10))
PRINT @f
```